# Flutter - How to display FCM notification outside notification bar like whatsapp

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented flutter push notification with FCM which is working perfectly for when the app is foreground, background and when the app get closed. But I am looking for a way to display my notification just will the way Whatsapp display popup notification when you are not inside it app just like a floating on top(Not in the notification bar this time.)see image attached:

[image]

As you can see in the image above, the user is inside the gallery app on the device, and the popup notification message of another app shows. Below is what my implement implement in flutter looks like:

```
   FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((message) {

            print(message);
        });
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

            print(message);
        });

FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {

            print(message);
});
```

My android manifest is like below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app_name">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />
 

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:label="app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationBootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name="MyNavigationService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="location" >
        </service>
        <receiver
            android:name="app_name.FirebaseBroadcastReceiver"
            android:exported="false"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <!--service
            android:name="app_name.java.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service-->

        <service
            android:name="app_name.service.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="A......"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
            android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:showWhenLocked="false"
            android:turnScreenOn="false"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
       
            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.SplashScreenDrawable"
                android:resource="@drawable/launch_background" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
         <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My flutter version for pub is : `firebase_messaging: ^13.0.4`

Comment: Any luck with the above question?

Comment: I think you should try ```awesome_notifications```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to work around a solution just in case anyone visits this page for a solution. I was able to work around it with `awesome_notification` It is a local notification pub.dev in flutter and I implement it in my `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage` So when the app is on background and FCM is triggered then the future function wrapping awesome notification is called as seen below:

call below in

```
void main() async{

 FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

}
```

And my `_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` is like below:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  bool isAllowed = await AwesomeNotifications().isNotificationAllowed();
 if (!isAllowed) return;


  await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: -1, // -1 is replaced by a random number
          channelKey: 'alerts',
          title: message.notification.title,
          body: message.notification.body,
          bigPicture: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
          largeIcon:'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/d406c736e7c4c57f5f61.png',
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.BigPicture,
          payload: {'notificationId': '1234567890'}),
      actionButtons: [
        NotificationActionButton(key: 'REDIRECT', label: 'Redirect'),

        NotificationActionButton(
            key: 'REPLY',
            label: 'Reply Message',
            requireInputText: true,
            actionType: ActionType.SilentAction
        ),
        NotificationActionButton(
            key: 'DISMISS',
            label: 'Dismiss',
            actionType: ActionType.DismissAction,
            isDangerousOption: true)
      ]
  );

}
```

Please note implement this in `main.dart`

Answer (score -1):

In case someone still seeking for the answer, this documentation solve my problem. Follow this documentation [Notifications - Flutterfire (Notification Channel #)](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/notifications/#notification-channels). The problem is, all notification will be sent to Miscellaneous channel if android notification channel id is not specified, so you need to specify the android notification channel and use a library the suggested by documentation to pop up the notification. Work on my project smoothly.

For your information i use:

- Flutter https://flutter.dev/
- Firebase https://firebase.google.com/
- FlutterFire https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview

For flutter version:

```
Flutter 3.13.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision ff5b5b5fa6 (6 weeks ago) • 2023-08-24 08:12:28 -0500
Engine • revision b20183e040
Tools • Dart 3.1.0 • DevTools 2.25.0
```

Please let me know if you need help. Thank you.